# Dimension of a span of three vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\{a_{1}, a_{2}, a_{3}, b_{1}, b_{2}, b_{3} \}$ be a set of vectors in $U$. Given that $\{\gamma_1 a_1 + \gamma_2 a_2, \beta_1 a_1 + \beta_2 a_3, \delta_1 a_2 + \delta_2 a_3\}$ are linearly independent vectors and $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^3\in sp\{b_1, b_2, b_3\}$. What is the dimension on a span of $b_1, b_2, b_3$?

Can't I conclude that its dim is 3 without any calculation? If so, what information adds me the fact that $\{\gamma_1 a_1 + \gamma_2 a_2, \beta_1 a_1 + \beta_2 a_3, \delta_1 a_2 + \delta_2 a_3\}$ are linearly independent vectors?

Comment: If you can conclude that the dimension is $3$ without any calculation, what is your reasoning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

{
  
    γ
    1
  
  
    a
    1
  
  +
  
    γ
    2
  
  
    a
    2
  
  ,
  
    β
    1
  
  
    a
    1
  
  +
  
    β
    2
  
  
    a
    3
  
  ,
  
    δ
    1
  
  
    a
    2
  
  +
  
    δ
    2
  
  
    a
    3
  
  }
 are linearly independent implys 
  {
  
    a
    1
  
  ,
  
    a
    2
  
  ,
  
    a
    3
  
  }
 is linearly independent then since 
  {
  
    a
    1
  
  ,
  
    a
    2
  
  ,
  
    a
    3
  
  }
  ⊆
  Span
  ⁡
  (
  {
  
    b
    1
  
  ,
  
    b
    2
  
  ,
  
    b
    3
  
  }
  )
 therefore dimension of  
  Span
  ⁡
  (
  {
  
    b
    1
  
  ,
  
    b
    2
  
  ,
  
    b
    3
  
  }
  )
 must at least be 3, also it can't exceed 3 , therefore dimension will be 3.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

Question 1: Is $\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$ a linearly independent set of vectors?  (Try assuming that they're not and see what goes wrong).

Question 2: Since $\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}\subseteq\operatorname{Span}(\{b_1,b_2,b_3\})$, what is a lower bound on the dimension of $\operatorname{Span}(\{b_1,b_2,b_3\})$?

Question 3: What is the maximum value of the dimension of $\operatorname{Span}(\{b_1,b_2,b_3\})$?